# Header and Footer template in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have implemented CKEditor in my project as per the requirement. I need to covert my html file to word document at the end on user input and my system is creating the document file perfectly. Now my client wants me to implement header and footer functionality same as word in my ckeditor edit area. What is the options available to implement such header footer functionality in ckeditor.?

Comment: Allow the client to input header and footer content is separate textarea/editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I made a patch for this solution.

```
i have created a table where i inserted all the information related to the file with the full path, the header text and the footer text and created one .net processes to pick the file from the path and add the header and footer to the file and at the end application will replace the new file with existing one. .net has very nice functionality to implement it.
```